# How can I draw the diagram in top left of the following image in latex?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

How can I draw the diagram in top left of the following image in latex?

[image]

Comment: By "top left" you mean the "ladder-like structure" *only*?

Answer (score 3):

Some `array`s and the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,shapes.geometric,fit}

\newcommand\AddSpa[2][6pt]{\hspace{#1}#2\hspace{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
\begin{array}[t]{c|l} 
2 & 12 \\ 
\hline 
2 & 6 \\ 
\hline 
3 & 3 \\ 
\hline 
& 1 
\end{array}\qquad
\begin{array}[t]{c|l} 
3 & 15 \\ 
\hline 
5 & 5\\ 
\hline 
& 1 
\end{array}\qquad
\begin{array}[t]{c|l} 
2 & 18 \\ 
\hline 
3 & 9 \\ 
\hline 
3 & 3 \\ 
\hline 
& 1 
\end{array}
\\[2cm]
\begin{array}{c@{\AddSpa{=}}c@{\AddSpa{\times}}c@{\AddSpa{\times}}c}
12 & \tikzmark{startcol1}2 & 2 & \tikzmark{startcol2}3 \\
15 &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& 5 & 3 \\
18 & \tikzmark{endcol1}2 & 3 & \tikzmark{endcol2}3 \\
\end{array}
\end{array}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate (aux1) at ([xshift=6pt,yshift=4pt]{pic cs:startcol1});
\coordinate (aux2) at ([xshift=6pt,yshift=4pt]{pic cs:startcol2});
\node[inner ysep=1pt,inner xsep=2pt,draw,ellipse,fit={(aux1) (pic cs:endcol1)}] {};
\node[inner ysep=1pt,inner xsep=2pt,draw,ellipse,fit={(aux2) (pic cs:endcol2)}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```